# addGeoJson Function inverse Lat and Lng?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm developing a google map function to display GEOJson Data in a map.

According to the web, the following points are in montreal :

- Point1 : lat = 45.555 and lng = -73.555
- Point2 : lat = 45.666 and lng  = -73.666

http://www.latlong.net/c/?lat=45.666&long=-73.666

So I've constructed my GEOJson data as follow (displaying two markers in Montreal):

```
var data_default = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [45.555, -73.555]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [45.666, -73.666]
            }
        }
    ] };
```

However, for this data, the following function :

```
map.data.addGeoJson(data);
```

Is not indicated the points in Montreal .... to have Montreal I should inverse the latitude and lng of the "coordinates" .. so my two points should have the following coordinates :  [-73.555, 45.555 ] [-73.666, 45.666] instead of [45.555, -73.555 ] [45.666,-73.666]

Is any one can explain to me why the addGeoJson of Google maps api is reading the points in an inverse way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) specifies coordinates as [longitude,latitude]. You have the coordinates backwards.

From [the spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#appendix-a-geometry-examples):

> **Point coordinates are in x, y order** (easting, northing for projected coordinates, **longitude, latitude for geographic coordinates**):

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.555, -73.555),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var data_default = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.555, 45.555]
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-73.666, 45.666]
      }
    }]
  };
  map.data.addGeoJson(data_default);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Ah ! Thank you ... that respond to my question !